# Localiztion in javascript

Tags: plugins, javascript, localization

Wordpress currently uses the `gettext` feature which is available in `php` but unfortunately not in `Javascript`.
I have searched this matter on the web and have come up with [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400106/translation-in-javascript-like-gettext-in-php). But there is a problem as the php file needs to be called through `Wordpress` system for the `gettext` feature to kick in.
I'm wondering if there is any way to call a php file inside Wordpress so we can use the built-in functions and variables?
Or if anyone can come up with a better solution, that'd be super.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WordPress has a nice function mainly for that [**wp_localize_script**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)

To use it first queue your script:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'My_Script_handle', 'path/to/script.js' );
```

then create an array of strings you want to localize:

```
$data = array( 
   'exit' => __( 'Exit','my-plugin-domain' ),
   'open' => __( 'Open','my-plugin-domain' ),
   'close' => __( 'Close','my-plugin-domain' ),
   'next' => __( 'Next','my-plugin-domain' ),
   'previous' => __( 'Previous','my-plugin-domain' )
);
```

and call it using wp_localize_script

```
wp_localize_script( 'My_Script_handle', 'mystrings', $data );
```

then you can access it in the page using JavaScript like this:

```
alert(mystrings.exit);
alert(mystrings.open);
```

...

you get the Idea.

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edit :) - just wanted to make it obvious the language domain is needed.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually a better way. I was using `wp_localize_script` for ajax url, but it didn't come to my mind that I can use it for l10n.

Comment: This one's one of the extremely good and well done answers! +1!